# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'input.txt' with int and matrix in python

Tags: python, graph, text-files, dijkstra

I have the following code:

```
import sys

class Graph():

    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.V = vertices
        self.graph = [[0 for column in range(vertices)]
            for row in range(vertices)]
            
    def printAnswer(self, dist, src):
        for node in range(self.V):
            if(node != src):
                print("node", src, "to node", node, ":", dist[node])
                
    def minDistance(self, dist, sptSet):
        min = 1000000009
        for u in range(self.V):
            if dist[u] < min and sptSet[u] == False:
                min = dist[u]
                min_index = u
        return min_index
        
    def dijkstraMinDist(self, src):
        dist = [1000000009] * self.V
        dist[src] = 0
        sptSet = [False] * self.V

        for cout in range(self.V):
            x = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet)
            sptSet[x] = True
            
            for y in range(self.V):
                if self.graph[x][y] > 0 and sptSet[y] == False and \
                        dist[y] > dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]:
                    dist[y] = dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]

        self.printAnswer(dist, src)


n = int(sys.argv[1])

g = Graph(n)
g.graph = []

for i in range(0, n):
    l = list(map(int, sys.argv[2].split()))
    g.graph.append(l)

for i in range(0, n):
    g.dijkstraMinDist(i)
```

And an input file:

```
4
0 2 -1 3
-1 0 1 5
2 3 0 -1
3 -1 4 0
```

And I would like to run **python3 file.py input.txt output.txt** from the command line, but when I run, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/c/Desktop/dijk/a.py", line 54, in <module>
n = int(sys.argv[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'input.txt'
```

Right now the output is on the command line, but I would also like to be printed in a text file output.txt

Comment: With `int(sys.argv[1])` you're telling python to cast the value of the first command line parameter to an integer value, but you're passing the string `input.txt` as the first command line parameter, which cannot be cast to an integer.

Comment: We don't need a bunch of code to figure out the error, just `n = int(sys.argv[1])`. When you ran the program, you used "input.txt" as the first argument. You could `print(sys.argv)` to see.

Comment: It appears you expect the filenames to somehow cause Python to read the files and interpret their contents - you'll have to do that yourself

Comment: In your own words, where you have written `n = int(sys.argv[1])`, *what do you expect that to do*? What do you think should be the resulting value of `n`, and *why*? In your own words, when you write `python3 file.py input.txt output.txt` at the command line, what do you expect this to accomplish? In particular, what do you expect `sys.argv` to end up containing, and why? In your own words, what do you think `sys.argv` is for, and how does it relate to the command line?

Comment: at this moment you runs `int('input.txt')`  but this way you can't get data from file. You have to `open()` file and `read()` all from file as one string  (or use `readlines()` to get it as list of line)

Comment: if you want to print in file then you also may need `open(...)` but with `write()` instead of `print()`. Or you can `print(file=handler_to_file, ...)` but it also need `handler_to_file = open(...)`

Comment: maybe first use `print( sys.argv[1] )` to see what you really have in variable. It is NOT value from file but only filename `input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't know how to work with files.

If you use `print( sys.argv[1] )` then you should see `"input.txt"`, not `"4"`

To work with file you have to use `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, `close()`

```
#fh = open("input.txt")  # get `file handler`
fh = open(sys.argv[1])

first_line = fh.readline()

n = int(first_line)
```

And later you can use again `fh.readline()` to get next line, or `fh.readlines()` to get list with or lines. or you can use `fh` directly with `for` to get lines

```
for line in fh:
    l = list(map(int, line.split()))
```